# Prime numbers not printing in Javascript

Tags: javascript, primes

I have the following code to find the prime numbers from 2 to 1000:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var primesarray = function(n) {
    var nums = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        nums.push("1");
    }

    return nums;
};

var primes = function(arr) {
    var i = 2;
    var primes = [];
    for (i = 2; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === "1")
            primes.push(i);
        for (j = 2; Math.pow(i, j) < arr.length - 1; j++ ) {
            arr[Math.pow(i,j)] = "0";
        }
    }
    return primes;
};

// Print to console
var fmt = function(arr) {
    return arr.join(",");
};

var k = 1000;
console.log("primes(" + k + ")");
console.log(fmt(primes(k)));
```

When I run the file, it just prints the first console.log line. I'm not seeing what's wrong here.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. It sounds to me like you 'found some code' but don't understand why it works. StackOverflow is not a good fit for these sort of questions.

Comment: Nothing calls the "primesarray" function.

Comment: Why are you using the _strings_ `"1"` and `"0"` as flags?

Comment: Also you should not be computing the sequence of *powers* of each newly-found prime - you want the *multiples*.

Answer (score 4):

The function `primes` is written to expect an array, but you're passing it an integer.

Did you mean `fmt(primes(primesarray(k)))`?

(That does at least print a list of numbers, but I'm afraid many of them are not primes!)

Comment: +1 for the same thought while I was playing with jsfiddle and to notice it does not actually work at all:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to *prime* you array ;)

```
var arr = primesarray(k)
```

like this

```
var k = 1000;
var arr = primesarray(k)
console.log(primes(arr));
console.log(fmt(primes(arr)));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ptSCm/)

Some actual solutions: http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/5033d10f77955e0002004142